# How to programmatically replace a field label and content before rendering?

Tags: 8, theming, hooks

I expected to be able to do it with `THEME_preprocess_field`, but the data at that point seems to have only the content's markup and not the label. I would need an instance where I can change both, because there's some mutual conditioning between them.

I also tried with `THEME_node_view` to no effect.

Note: I want to do this in a theme, not a custom module.

Comment: It doesn't, I would need a way to do it in the custom theme, not in a custom module

Comment: Alter hooks also work on themes.

Comment: This one does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I expected to be able to do it with THEME_preprocess_field, but the
> data at that point seems to have only the content's markup

There are more template variables:

*field.html.twig:*

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation for a field.
 * 
 * ...
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - attributes: HTML attributes for the containing element.
 * - label_hidden: Whether to show the field label or not.
 * - title_attributes: HTML attributes for the title.
 * - label: The label for the field.
 * - multiple: TRUE if a field can contain multiple items.
 * - items: List of all the field items. Each item contains:
 *   - attributes: List of HTML attributes for each item.
 *   - content: The field item's content.
 * - entity_type: The entity type to which the field belongs.
 * - field_name: The name of the field.
 * - field_type: The type of the field.
 * - label_display: The display settings for the label.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_field()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
```

So you can change for example `label`:

*mytheme.theme:*

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for field.html.twig.
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  $variables['label'] = 'foo';
}
```